# How to add External Selenium jar and Test NG framework for multiple projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I practiced the sample of selenium web-driver using java 
This is my first project in Selenium  Web driver as live project in java+ Selenium.

I would like to add general selenium and TestNg jars for multiple projects. How to make general jars that can be accessed for multiple Projects.

My need is to make centralized access for multiple projects in Eclipse

[image: Example of Two Projects]

Comment: You can consider using maven pom file. it will download the files from internet. No need to keep it for each project. It will be shared across your system.

Comment: @Murthi:  it works